# mitmproxy flow multiply request for

Tags: python-3.x, mitmproxy

I would like to achieve with mitmproxy and a custom python script to duplicate some requests multiple times.

As a example if the client does a post request to aaa.bbb.ccc and the url contains as a string ["test","runner"] it takes this request and sends it 10 times.

```
amount = 10
wordwatch = ["test","dev"]
domain = "aaa.bbb.ccc"

def request(context, flow):
    print(type(flow.request.url))
    if domain in flow.request.url:
        if any(s in flow.request.url for s in wordwatch):
            for i in range(0, amount + 1):
                flow.response
```

The problem I have is I neither get an error or something in the output. Also on the serverside when I watch the apache log I can't even see the requests incoming. The server uses only http so it shouldn't be a https/certificate issue. It is very good possible that I misunderstood the documentation and samples on [Manual](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-scripting/) [Samples](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-overview/) .

Comment: Based on your description the functionality of mitmproxy to replay a request should be what you need. See this sample script: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#duplicate-modify-replay

Comment: Hi @Robert , thanks for the response, i know this sample already. Problem with this is it duplicates the whole flow instead of only the request that comes from the client. So if a client sends a request to the server, it should automatically send the request 10x but ignore if there was no response yet from the first request. So far i was still not able to do it. In case i find it out i am happy to update the question and include the answer.